# Reason for operator new returning void*;

Tags: c++, memory-management

What is the point/reason for `operator new` returning `void*`?

I've tried to come up with ideas as to why such an operator version exists, but I couldn't come up with one.

Comment: what else should it return?

Comment: `operator new` is a memory allocation function. It just allocates a chunk of "uninitialized" memory, so it does not make any sense to return anything else than a typeless pointer. Maybe you should learn about the difference between `operator new` and the `new` _expression_. The latter returns a "typed" pointer.

Comment: _"**operator new** is a memory allocation function"_ - except for those overloads used by placement `new`.

Comment: It would make sense for operator new (and malloc) to return a type that is implicitly convertible to any pointer type, which sadly isn't the case in C++.

Comment: operator new is just allocating untyped memory. The new expression you usually will construct an object in that memory and that will return a typed pointer.

Comment: @Marc what type would that look like?

Comment: @Neil like `void*` in C.

Comment: @MarcGlisse That may be convenient in C, but in C++ it would cause a massive amount of problems.

Comment: @Marc so std::string * s = ::operator new(3); would do ... what?

Comment: @MarcGlisse `operator new` (and `malloc`) does not create a [C++ Object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) in the memory it returns.  So returning a pointer which is _"...implicitly convertible..."_ to a pointer to object would likely lead to Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @RichardCritten Actually, it [does](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#13.sentence-3), but only in some [specific cases](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general#9.sentence-5) and only since C++20.

Comment: A reasonable alternative would be for `operator new` to return `std::byte*`, but that could easily be misused and result in undefined behavior, and cause a massive amount of problems, and require more casting to use.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Conceptually? It could return a proxy with an implicit conversion 
operator template which does the actual allocation and also constructs objects of the inferred (template argument) type. Other languages do something like this, and it would be valid C++. But of course that isn't the job of `::operator new`, despite its idiotically misleading name.

Comment: @Piotr sometimes the comment section here on SO is deaf to the level of expertise/experience the question/questioner possesses. As we have witnessed here, the banter/language lawyering is not really pertinent to the question asked. Still; good banter.